# 'flutter_ijkplayer' setFileDataSource Showing a Black screen before video loading.How can i fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, ijkplayer

I was making a video player in Android with flutter.
I am using 'flutter_ijkplayer' for video playback.
https://github.com/CaiJingLong/flutter_ijkplayer

My problem is every time i set 'setFileDataSource' and play it shows a black screen before playing the video.I may be a blank screen showing before loading a video.I want to remove this black screen and play video without any blackout.

[image]

Here in the screen record, I am calling below code on the play button click.That means same video loading again and again.

```
controller.ijkMediaController.setFileDataSource(File(controller.videoPath), autoPlay: true);
```

Comment: Can you verify the problem is the video OR the video player. Download the file available at pipepath, locally and open it on your PC's internal video player. When no black screen is visible, you could the problem is in the video player. Then we can start debugging at the right location.

Comment: I am wondering what you're trying to do with the video, because the current FFMPEG command only does an audio filter and forces video format. If FLV files are required this could be done in an easier way, and for the audio filter. In my eyes you are not filtering out a specific range of frequencies, so it seems like quite a normal range and therefore unneccessary.

Comment: Can you please share some more information, like video of the issue or sample code where I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Animesh Bhardwaj. Question Updated

Comment: @LinsLouis, As per this source, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41156#issuecomment-634555243

This is usually caused by a frame of video black at the start or end of the track. Open this in Quicktime player and move the play head to the start and end and look for a black frame.

If there is, edit it out in a video editing application.


Let me know, it work for you or not.

Comment: Not the problem of video, I can confirm that